# Email from one after-PhD-scientist to another after-PhD-scientist. Private or institutional email address?

Tags: email, communication

Suppose I (a senior postdoc in Europe) write an email to another not-student scientist (a postdoc or a professor also in Europe) that does not know me nor directly nor by publications. I am either asking about writing a common project or about an open position or some scientific question related to their work.

I see many disadvantages in using institutional emails so usually I use a private Gmail one. However *most* often people never answer (and I am pretty sure my emails are not bad enough to offend anyone or boring enough to generate zero interest). I got used to think that people are just too lazy/too overwhelmed with many things to answer every random  guy with a PhD with at least one sentence.

But recently I started to work in a place where people are extremely paranoid about internet security to the point that they mark *all* incoming emails from other institutions (let along free mailservers) in a special way. So I started to wonder: what if many of my emails (that were most often sent to institutional addresses, since usually they are the ones publicly available) were lost in spam or even deleted automatically due to paranoia of people setting mail server configuration?

So what is your experience? Do you think my problem getting replies from people can be related to me using my private email? Or it is just yet another one harsh reality of Academia one has to accept?

Comment: Why would you not use a professional email address when you are a professional trying to establish communication with another professional, for professional reasons?

Comment: @Nij because the mailservers are often down at unpredictable moments, my position is temporary (thus the address as well) and the access to the mail is much more convenient with Gmail

Comment: There are trivial solutions to each of those problems, none of which require creating larger problems by using a personal address to do professional tasks.

Comment: Further, if your employer is requiring more strict protocol around the use of the professional email, you are deliberately circumventing those protocols. Unless you are the person who decided them, you do not have the authority nor likely the expertise to justify doing so. This is a reason for immediate termination in many jurisdictions, let alone the potential for liability if (or even when) things go wrong.

Comment: At my institution, mail coming in from outside gets an "[EXTERNAL]" prepended to the subject line. I'm not sure I'd call that 'extremely paranoid' but perhaps I know too many cybersecurity folks. But use your institutional email.

Comment: @Nij my employer did not even bother to provide me with a contract in a language that I understand, so I don't really feel obliged to follow every comma in their protocols (which I could not possibly understand), especially when all they are written for medical doctors and for me all they do is hindering my performance as a researcher. May I ask what are those trivial solutions you are referring to?

Comment: If they provided the contract in the legal language of their jurisdiction, they did everything a reasonable employer should; I'd be more concerned if they gave a language option because of the ease through which this creates problems and potential abuse. Translating a legal document requires fluency in both languages, plus a knowledge of the legal phrasing. If you want one done, it is your obligation to get it, because it's your burden to understand what you are signing.

Answer (score 2):

If your institution gives you an email address and maintains it, they expect you to use it for professional communication. I've been retired for about ten years and still use my university email for *almost all* communication, not just professional.

If you are no longer affiliated with the institution, but they still maintain your email address, then you can use the address initially but explain to a new professional contact that your affiliation has ended. Once you make contact, you can decide to use a more private email if that seems advisable.

But, as you note, an email from a gmail address could come from anyone, where a .edu or .ac address indicates that you are an academic.

For industrial employees, the employer may have rules, of course. This might be your situation, since you are seeing some paranoia. But using a different email address is hardly a security measure.

Comment: They may or may not expect it, but from the perspective of an individual researcher there are some good reasons to prefer other email addresses - permanence, already established communication channels etc. Anyway, yes, making initial contact from an institutional address can certainly look more professional.

Comment: @buffy I don't quite see your point. If you say that institutional email should be used for professional communication, then why do you use it for almost all communication? Looks like you just suggest another extreme. I am talking about within-Academia communication (my paranoid employer is a clinic, related to a university)

Comment: I don't know for professors, but my experience as student/postdoc is to expect your institutional email to silently not function any more the day after your contract ends (i.e. you cannot access it any more, incoming emails are silently dropped). Some universities grant exemptions of a couple of months (with a chunk of burocracy required), but not for very long.

Comment: "But, as you note, an email from a gmail address could come from anyone, where a .edu or .ac address indicates that you are an academic." Spoofing sender e-mail address is pretty trivial, so a mail coming from a .edu or .ac.uk could be coming from anyone. Moreover, many academics work at institutions that do not have .edu or .ac e-mail addresses.

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX This varies widely, but I've never heard of "silently ceasing to function," which seems like the most extreme possible option.

Comment: @KevinArlin: Well, tbh, for most institutions where I have been working, I cannot say how long exactly the mailbox continued to exist after I did not have access any more. I do know of one institution where I got the very same email address again after being away for several years, and there I know: people told me they tried to contact me there while I was not working there, and when I again got access to that email address there were no emails older than ≈start of contract date. At another institution I and a bunch of colleagues lost email access when the IT department was not notified of the

Comment: renewal of the contract. In this case, the accounts were not yet deleted, once we had access again after a few days, our old email account contents were still there. I have not seen any institution commiting to an account will be deleted within x days. And I'm pretty certain most institution over here drop emails that go to non-existent accounts rather than allowing spam bots to find out which addresses actually exist.
Anyways: you cannot relay on the email working any given amount of time after contract ends, unless you do the required burocracy, which typically has limits.